# Flutter File picker unable to select image from Android Gallery

Tags: android, flutter, file-upload, android-image, filepicker

I am using [file_picker 5.0.1](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), while selecting image from Android device Gallery app it shows this error.

```
I/FilePickerDelegate(26740): User cancelled the picker request
```

This is the code snippet, I am using to call file picker

```
 FilePickerResult? result =
                            await  FilePicker.platform
                                .pickFiles(
                              type: FileType.image,
                                    allowMultiple: false,
                                    allowCompression: false,
                                    });
                            
                            if (result != null) {
                              print(result.files.length);


                            }
```

My flutter version : 3.0.5
Android compileSdkVersion : 31
Android minSdkVersion : 19
Android targetSdkVersion : 31

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/issues/717#issuecomment-847801191

Updated my `AndroidManifest.xml`

**Before**

```
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

**After**

```
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: instead of "singleTask" use "singleInstancePerTask"

Answer (score 0):

Check permission is granted and at least one album app is installed in the phone. Also you can try

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
    type: FileType.custom,
    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
  );
```

or use this package
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Tried https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker, same issue